# phantomjs and passing imagedata as json

Tags: json, phantomjs, binary-data

Can I use phantomjs to create an image of the contents of `<div><iframe ..></div>` (The div contains an iframe)

how do I make this image (binary data) as part of a json ? , as `({img: binary data})` ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to load the iframe by itself? If you can achieve that then there's no reason why you can't call `var base64string = page.renderBase64();` to get a base-64 encoded string. See the [API for renderBase64()](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render-base64.html).

You can re-create the image later by evaluating `img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64string;`.

Comment: PP, thanks. I wanted to write this comment, but looks like I edited your answer. sorry for that. I wanted to ask if you would be able to explain the first part of your answer a bit. second part is clear though.

Comment: Can you [interrogate your iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp) to find its URL? e.g. `var url = page.evaluate( function() { return iframe.src; } );` and then set your page location to it, e.g. `page.open( url, callback );`?

Comment: very basic question. can this be added as a javascript src in any webpage ? If so, how ? I tried this in a standalone mode and executing this with phantomjs.exe from the command line.